# GUI PyQt4 и многопоточность

Tags: pyqt4, python-2.7

```
#!C:\usr\Python\python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt4 import uic
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from TxtToPDF import PDF
def selectFile():
    window.File.setText(QFileDialog.getOpenFileName())
def ConvertTxtToPDF(File):
    window.ConvertTxtToPDFButton.setText(u"Конвертация...")
    window.ConvertTxtToPDFButton.setCheckable(True)
    window.ConvertTxtToPDFButton.setChecked(True)
    pdf = PDF()
    pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', uni=True)
    pdf.print_chapter(2, 'THE PROS AND CONS', File)
    pdf.output(File[:-3]+'pdf', 'F')
    QMessageBox.information(window, u"Info",u"Convert files in "+File[:-3]+u"pdf",buttons=QMessageBox.Close,defaultButton=QMessageBox.Close)
    window.ConvertTxtToPDFButton.setText(u"Конвертировать")
    window.ConvertTxtToPDFButton.setChecked(False)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = uic.loadUi("ui.ui")
window.show()
QObject.connect(window.SelectTxtFile, SIGNAL('clicked()'), selectFile)
QObject.connect(window.ConvertTxtToPDFButton, SIGNAL('clicked()'), lambda : ConvertTxtToPDF(unicode(window.File.text())))
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Проблема заключается в том, что сначала выполняется код:

```
pdf = PDF()
pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.print_chapter(2, 'THE PROS AND CONS', File)
pdf.output(File[:-3]+'pdf', 'F')
```

, а затем

```
window.ConvertTxtToPDFButton.setText(u"Конвертация...")
window.ConvertTxtToPDFButton.setCheckable(True)
window.ConvertTxtToPDFButton.setChecked(True)
```

Я пытался использовать многопоточность, но кнопка изменяется только после сохранения PDF.

Comment: Код функции `ConvertTxtToPDF` у вас выполяется в правильном порядке. Дело в том, что за отрисовку и изменение состояния графических объектов отвечает петля `QApplication`, а ей управление возвращается только после завершения работы функции `ConvertTxtToPDF`. Поэтому, обновление интерфейса происходит после выхода из функции.

Comment: Спасибо чувак! Но как мне организовать код чтобы программа работала нормально? Не очень хорошо знаю Python пока.